# Windows 8.1: search does not provide any results from hard drive even though it is indexed, and the index has finished building?

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-search

My Windows 8.1 setup involves an SSD and an NTFS formatted HDD.

I have specifically asked Windows to index the HDD:

[image]

I have given Windows lots of time to rebuild the index (and my computer is overpowered in terms of processing power for most applications).

[image]

My hard drive is NTFS formatted and allows indexing:

[image]

It has no errors:

[image]

Finally, I have restarted my computer.

Yet, I cannot find files that are located inside of it. Notice that there is a file that clearly has model in its name, yet searching for model inside the folder RESEARCH comes up with no results.

[image]

[image]

**Why is this happening?**

---

As per Karan's suggestions, I checked the access settings for SYSTEM:

[image]

Comment: Does `*model*` as the search string help?

Comment: @Karan No, same thing.

Comment: For A: as well as the RESEARCH and Week_53 folders, can you check Properties > Security tab and see whether SYSTEM is allowed full control for all of them? Also, did you try adding only RESEARCH to the search index to see if that makes a difference?

Comment: @Karan I have added an image to the post showing what the security settings are like. They are the same for A:, RESEARCH and Week_53, so I have only included one picture.

Comment: Looks ok, but you might want to censor your email address. In `File Explorer > Tools menu > Folder options > Search tab` ensure *Include subfolders* and *Find partial matches* are both checked. If that doesn't help, I suppose you can try removing A: from the search index, adding only RESEARCH, rebuilding (wait for it to complete) and then see whether it works.

Comment: @Karan Here's what I see under `Folder Options > Search tab`: http://i.imgur.com/iPumHnS.png -- I don't see the options you are mentioning?

Comment: Oh yeah, my mistake, I was looking at the options on my Win7 PC when I typed that. So... I guess try the other suggestion?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23072/discussion-between-user89-and-karan).